# Sitecore page only displaying if signed in

Tags: sitecore

I have a page that is published. The page looks fine in preview/experience editor but it does not load if i'm not signed into Sitecore admin.

I have published the entire site. All other pages are fine.

Once I hit the broken page, all other pages become broken. I have never seen this before.

This started once i setup alias for this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias must also be published they are stored below /sitecore/system/Aliases

A shot in the darkness to give a possible reason for the all other pages become broken.
perhaps you switch the language, when the url start with a language code for example /da/testpage  you go to the Danish language, /ja-jp/testpage go to Japanese language. and if there is no content or language fallback for that language, it look not nice, and looks to become broken.

Sitecore has a language cookie named website#lang depend on the configured site name. There the language is stored, so if an url does not contain a language code and there is a language code cookie, Sitecore uses that language code.

If your site is in "en" language you can fix it by entering a url started with /en/
or by deleting the language cookie.

so if this is the case in your situation, you properly have a language code in your url alias.

Comment: i think you're on to something. The alias that was create is "/ce"

Comment: the client wanted to keep the alias so i created a 301 redirect. Thank you!! i had no idea the page was changing languages at first.